# von neumann algebras and measurable spaces

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras

I've read some pages on links between von neumann (VN) algebras and measurable spaces ([Spectra of $C^*$ algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5036/spectra-of-c-algebras) and [Non-commutative geometry from von Neumann algebras?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3150/non-commutative-geometry-from-von-neumann-algebras)), but I can't get the following:

- VN algebras are C*-algebras
- C*-algebras are equivalent to compact separated topological spaces
- VN are equivalent to measurable spaces

How come then we can find measurable spaces which are not topological spaces if any VN algebra is a C*-algebra? I suspect my question to be silly but I don't have the answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By Gel'fand-Naimark, there is an isomorphism $L_\infty(\mu) \cong C(K)$ for some hyperstonean space $K$, so you should perhaps google for the term *hyperstonean/hyperstonian* then. One can even have `a formula' for that compact space: $K=\mbox{Stone space}(\wp(\Omega)/\mathcal{N}_\mu)$, where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is your measure space and $\mathcal{N}_\mu$ denotes the σ-ideal of $\mu$-null sets. Please have a look on vol. 1 of Takesaki's book for more details.

Comment: Thanks Tomek. Then I guess that the answer to my problem would be that there are measurable spaces which are not Hyperstonian, which seems wrong since in the references I gave an equivalence is pointed out between these two categories. So I still have a problem with how come there are measurable/hyperstonian spaces which are not topological spaces whereas all VN algebras are C*-algebras?

Comment: Unless VN algebras are equivalent to $\mathcal{L}^\infty([0;1])$ only, and all measurable spaces not isomorphic to it are pathological and may not be topological spaces, in which case there is an equivalence between VN algebras - Hyperstonian spaces - "Nice enough" measurable spaces. I guess the "nice enough" property is what Pavlov is calling "Localizable measurable spaces". So the question now is:

Comment: To be hyperstonian is a topological property (a property of a topological space, not of a measure space). By the above, every localisable measure space gives rise to a hyperstonian (compact) space and vice-versa. Separably acting commutative vNAs exhaust the list: $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is finite or countably infinite, $L_\infty[0,1]$ or $L_\infty[0,1]\oplus \ell_\infty(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Of course, one has to be careful. People often make a blanket assumption that measure spaces are always localisable. I can't think of any *interesting* non-localisable measure spaces though.

Comment: Ok, so why call vNA theory "non-commutative measure theory" and point its difference with respect to C*-algebras theory ("non-commutative topology") since in vNT all what distinguishes measure theory from topology (mainly measurable spaces not being topological) is absent (we are restricted to LMS, which are topological)?

Comment: No, vNAs carry primarily their ultraweak topology (the weak*-topology arising from the *unique* predual). This gives you Borel functional calculus in vNAs for example any many more things. vNAs are studied more from this (measure-theoretic-in-nature) perspective.

Comment: Ok so do we agree that vNA theory is just a specific case of C*-algebras theory, which can be studied from measure-theoretic perspective thanks to the topology inherited from the predual, but is not a separate theory, so that calling it "non-commutative measure theory" is misleading? A $true$ non-commutative measure theory should start by a duality between $all$ measurable spaces and some special kind of algebras. Do you have any idea on what kind of algebras is this?

Comment: No, I do not agree with the statement that vNA theory is just a specific case of C*-algebras theory. This might be of interest to you: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/grabowski/files/brown.pdf

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for all your answers, I'll have a look at the reference you gave and think more about these issues.

Comment: @Tomek: "I can't think of any interesting non-localiszble measure spaces" --- how about one-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly recommend Segal's original paper *Equivalences of Measure Spaces*
[American Journal of Mathematics
Vol. **73**, No. 2 (1951), pp. 275-313], where he introduced localizable spaces, since this was before the terminology took off.
In it he shows that an arbitrary measure space has maximal abelian (i.e. strongly closed) $L^\infty$ algebra if and only if it is localizable.
So there do exist measure spaces which for which $L^\infty(X)$ is not a von Neumann algebra. But (and it's a big but), if you're at all interested in integration, then the class of localizable measure spaces is really as large a class of interesting measure spaces as there is. The following excerpt explains why:

*The class of measure spaces with these properties (we call such spaces "localizable") constitutes in some ways a more natural generalization of the $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, than the class of arbitrary measure spaces. In particular, for a measure space to be localizable is equivalent to the validity for the space of the conclusion of the Radon-Nikodym theorem, or alternatively to the conclusion of the Riesz representation theorem for continuous linear functionals on the Banach space of integrable functions. Every measure space is metrically equivalent (by which we mean there is a measure-preserving isomorphism between the $\sigma$-finite measure rings - roughly speaking this means the spaces are equivalent as far as integration over them is concerned) to a localizable space, and this latter space is essentially unique.*

The point of view being held here is that measure theory is not about defining odd pathological measure spaces, but about all the cool stuff you can build on the nicer spaces: integration theory, probability theory, dynamical systems, stochastic processes, ergodic theory. And all that interesting stuff can be done, or is being worked out, in von Neumann algebras.

So von Neumann algebras capture the integration bit of measure theory.

Regarding your point in the comments: "**since in vNT all what distinguishes measure theory from topology (mainly measurable spaces not being topological) is absent (we are restricted to LMS, which are topological)?**" The category of localizable measure spaces and measurable maps is equivalent to the category of hyperstonean topological spaces and hyperstonean maps - this is not a subcategory of topological spaces and continuous maps - the maps between these spaces have to preserve an extra structure, namely a family of normal measures. 
(Just like the category of topological spaces is not a subcategory of sets, because again they have different morphisms, but there is a forgetful functor Top-->Set).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ollie. Your point of HypStone not being a subcategory of Top makes it easier to accept the idea that vNA are not a particular case of C*-algebras, but from your answer I would deduce that a better name for vNAs should be "non-commutative integration theory" and not "non-commutative measure theory" because of the pathological cases I was evoking. One more general question: how come topology is not considered a particular case of measure theory since you can get the primitive notion (open sets) from the generator of the Borel set, hence all other notions (continuity etc)?

Comment: And by topology I mean HKB topology, not less rigid versions which clearly can't be reduced to measure theory. PS: I understand Segal's point of pathological cases not being essential, but this view of measure theory might turn out to be too restrictive (who knows how measure theory will develop) so I prefer to consider it in full generality, and explicitely point at the integration part of it when dealing with category equivalences like vNA, hyperstonian spaces etc

Comment: If you're worried about excluding these pathological measure spaces, you should note the same problem also applies to $C^*$-algebras: we are dualising only compact Hausdorff spaces, not general topological spaces!

I'm not sure what you mean by getting the open sets from the generator of the Borel set. The topology of a Borel space can't be recovered from its $\sigma$-algebra - for instance $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ with their standard topologies are not homeomorphic - however the corresponding measurable spaces are isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, you are right concerning C*-algebras, though the fact we are restricted is pretty obvious so it didn't really bother me, whereas vNAs got me confused with the subtelties about localizability, integration etc. But now its all clear. Concerning the second point, I thought we could recover the topology from the $\sigma$-algebra through the generator of the $\sigma$-algebra, but your examples of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ made me understand I was wrong. Thanks for your answer which helped me on the "psychological" level, and to all others for their (technically) detailed answers!

Comment: “the maps between these spaces have to preserve an extra structure”: such maps are precisely open maps of hyperstonean spaces.  So hyperstonean spaces with such morphisms do form a subcategory of topological spaces, albeit not a full subcategory.  See Theorem 1.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05284.

Answer (score 10):

To make things simpler let us deal with unital $C^*$-algebras. Then the category of commutative (unital) $C^*$-algebras and unital $*$-homomorphisms is dual to the category of compact topological spaces and continuous maps. This is generally what is meant by $C^*$-algebra theory is "non-commutative topology" because we just drop the commutative assumptions. Now it is true that von Neumann algebras are $C^*$-algebras but in general they are not a particularly interesting case. The easiest way to see this is that for a commutative $C^*$-algebra, $A$, then by Gelfand's theorem we know that is it isomorphic to the continuous complex valued function on some compact space, call it $X$, (we need that $A$ is unital). However, it is a fairly easy exercise to show that $X$ is metrizable $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ is separable for the norm topology. Also a von Neumann algebra is separable for the norm topology $\Leftrightarrow$ it is finite dimensional. It is natural to restrict to the separable case (so that you can get a handle on a dense subset and from there do analysis). So if you restrict to the norm topology viewing von Neuman algebras as $C^*$-algebras is not particularly useful.

However, there is another topology on von Neumann algebras for which many algebras are separable. This is called the untraweak topology and comes from the fact that the algebra is the dual of a banach space. In the commutative case, $L^\infty([0, 1])$, this topology amounts to convergence in measure. So the topology on the von Neumann algebra that makes it manageable remembers the measure structure of $[0, 1]$ NOT the topological structure of $[0, 1]$. With this in mind there is a similar equivalence of categories between commutative vNA with $*$-homomorphisms and measure spaces with measurable maps.

Further, because of this difference in topologies, the two theories have quite a different "flavor", much of it comes down to which version of the spectral theorem one is allowed to apply.

Finally, one more things worth pointing out is that it is common said that a von Neumann algebra is the non-commutative analogue of a measure space. This is not quite true. The correct statement is that a vNA is the analogue of a $\textit{measured}$ space. Recall that a measured space is is a space with a $\sigma$-algebra and a choice of measure 0 sets, but not a specific choice of measure. This is the proper analogue because you don't get the "measure" until you choose a state, or weight, or the algebra.

Comment: Thanks Owen for this clarification. But then I don't see the difference between what you said and what I said at some point, quote "Ok so do we agree that vNA theory is just a specific case of C*-algebras theory, which can be studied from measure-theoretic perspective thanks to the topology inherited from the predual". I understand that vNA are not interesting with the C*-algebras norm topology, but being able to endow them with a nicer topology and find many results is just a nice feature of this particular subset of C*-algebras. Tomek not agreeing with this makes me feel something is wrong..

Comment: The main issue to me is this (and I am repeating myself): vNAs being equivalent to nice measured spaces (localizable), they are not general enough to be called "noncommutative measured spaces" since one can probably find noncommutative analogs for non localizable measured spaces, and no correspondent vNA will be found for them.

Comment: Small quibble about "separability" - aren't ultrapowers (borh VN and Cstar) useful things to consider?

Comment: @Yemon: Yes, I did gloss over this. Though to be honest, ultrapowers are a convenient language to talk about sequences of separable algebras, and every use of ultrapowers that I know of fits into this role.

Comment: What is the precise meaning of "[the ultraweak] topology amounts to convergence in measure"? Surely you can't mean that the topologies are the same: the topology of convergence in measure is metrizable while the ultraweak topology is not metrizable except in the finite-dimensional case.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, by I thought that they agreed on the unit ball.

Comment: Off-topic, but over at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466382/i-need-help-to-prove-theorem-of-hahn-banach the purported answer seems to be faulty, I don't think the attempt to construct a biorthogonal basis works (I am not on MSE so cannot comment there. If you let me know when you see this comment then I will delete it)

Comment: @Yemon: I got your comment, I don't see the issue though, except that maybe you don't want to use axiom of choice to get a basis (since it is weaker than HB no?), but for a finite dimension subspace of $X$ it should be fine.

Comment: @OwenSizemore Sure you can take a Hamel basis of X, but then how is one supposed to use Hahn-Banach to construct a dual basis whose members are *continuous* linear functionals? (Also, the question forgets to assume dim$(X) \geq n$)

Comment: @Yemon: Doesn't HB do this for you? A bounded linear function on a subspace (which these duals function are when restricted to the predual(original) basis) can be extended to a bounded linear function on the whole space, with the same bound (norm). This is how i've always thought of the non-geometric version of HB, is this not right?

Comment: @OwenSizemore Yes, but why should the continuous extension vanish on all other basis vectors? (Hamel bases of inf-dim Ban spaces are always uncountable, BTW)

Comment: @Yemon: Ah ok yes, Now I see. I will add a comment on post.